# Можно ли прочитать позицию и размеры стороннего приложения?

Tags: python, tkinter

Можно ли прочитать позицию и размеры окна стороннего приложения .exe? Как? (желательно с помощью tkinter) Для позиционирования окна .pyw приложения.
Можно ли привязать .pyw к уже готовому приложению?

Comment: Уточните в вопросе, какая ОС имеется ввиду?

Comment: Средствами tkinter нельзя. Если речь про Windows, то можно средствами WinAPI узнать положение и размеры окон сторонних приложений.

Comment: Windows 10. Нужно, чтобы приложение .pyw в интерактивном режиме подстраивалось под размеры окна .exe приложения.   insolor, как?

Comment: WinAPI функции FindWindow (найти окно по классу окна и/или по заголовку), GetWindowRect, вызывать с помощью библиотеки pywin32

Answer (score 0):

Вот как-то так:

```
import win32gui

def print_window_info(hwnd, *args):
    rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
    x, y = rect[0], rect[1]
    w, h = rect[2] - x, rect[3] - y
    title = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
    print(f"Окно {title}:")
    print(f"    позиция (X,Y): ({x}, {y})")
    print(f"     размер (W,H): ({w}, {h})")

# можно пройтись по всем окнам
win32gui.EnumWindows(print_window_info, None)

# или попытаться найти конкретное
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow("Notepad", None)
if hwnd:
    print_window_info(hwnd)
```

Результат для окна Notepad'а:

```
Окно Безымянный — Блокнот:
    позиция (X,Y): (96, 111)
     размер (W,H): (1528, 850)
```

Comment: А как выбрать конкретное приложение? сравнить по tittle? Если у приложения несколько окон как выбрать 'более активное' ?